# Double ToString problems

Tags: c#, .net, double, tostring

I have this:

```
textBoxNano.Text = stats.Nano.ToString();
```

The problem is when the `stats.Nano` (which is a double) gets with more digits, the `textBoxNano` displays it:

> 1E-06

What I want is to display larger numbers normally.Ex:

> 0.0000001

I tried to pass the `.ToString("G10");` but nothing changed.

**EDIT:** 
Ok I changed it to:

```
textBoxNano.Text = stats.Nano.ToString("F10");
```

but now I have another problem. It displays 1 like this 1.0000000000
How to hide the zeros remaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0)

I used `.ToString("#,0.####################");` which outputs `0.01` and not `0.01000000000000000`

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the general format string `G` - use `F` for fixed point.

```
textBoxNano.Text = stats.Nano.ToString("F10");
```

This will produce (as per your example):

```
0.0000001000
```

Take a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to see the different options.

Comment: @Bosak - With a whole big number, you need to specify a larger precision. I tried "G15" and it worked fine with 100000000000.